# Gmail ICS: How do I mark as not spam?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, gmail, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I've got a Samsung S3, and on my old SGS I could mark a spam as not spam.

How do I do this in my ICS GMail? The feature seems to have healed up.

Others have seen this also:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1525799

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't mark mails as *not spam*.
Instead you have to label it inbox. To do this on the bottom action bar, hit labels and tick inbox.

It seems that this is equivalent as all future emails go straight to the inbox.

Comment: And what if its already in your inbox? Gmail thinks an account is compromised and so the links in the e-mail don't work - but I know this is genuine and now can't follow any links :-(